Как автоматически разборкировать связку ключей в debian 12?
Включен autologin. Пароль обнулял, но это не помогло - всё равно пишет, что связка ключей не была разблокирована и просит пароль пользователя.
Нужно чтобы как в Windows - вошёл в систему не вводя никаких паролей, но приложения, где сохранены пароли, спокойно авторизуются ничего не спрашивая.
Как это настроить в debian 12 (оболочка xfce)?

Сам я не любитель автологина, но (настраивал знакомой) много лет тому, и ещё пару-тройуку лет назад работало — https://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?t=146587 Как раз у меня в планах переустановиться с 10-ки на свежие потуги (почти всю жизнь в этой связке.). Если что завтра-послезавтра дополню. и ELSE я правильно помню последовательность, то "связки ключей" никак не связаны с этим моментом, и идут следом, а не перед "логином".
